# CLIPS How can I create a print out for when the values inserted are not any of the options?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system

I need to add to my program a print for when the user inserts values that dont correspond to the existing fruits on my program.

```
    (clear)
(deftemplate fruta 
    (slot nombre) 
    (multislot color
        (allowed-values naranja amarillo morado rojo verde)) 
    (slot semilla
        (allowed-values hueso multiple)) 
    (multislot tipo-piel
        (allowed-values aterciopelada lisa rugosa)) 
    (slot crece-en
        (allowed-values arbol planta))
)

(defrule in-color
    =>
    (printout t "Ingrese el color de la fruta: ")
    (assert (color (read)))
)

(defrule in-semilla
    =>
    (printout t "Ingrese el tipo de semilla de la fruta: ")
    (assert (semilla (read)))
)

(defrule in-tipo-piel
    =>
    (printout t "Ingrese el tipo de piel de la fruta: ")
    (assert (tipo-piel (read)))
)

(defrule in-crece-en
    =>
    (printout t "Donde crece la fruta (arbol o planta): ")
    (assert (crece (read)))
)

(defrule buscar-fruta
    (color ?color)
    (semilla ?semilla)
    (tipo-piel ?tipo-piel)
    (crece ?crece-en)
    (fruta (nombre ?nombre) (color $? ?color $?) (semilla ?semilla) (tipo-piel $? ?tipo-piel $?) (crece-en ?crece-en))
    =>
    (printout t "La fruta a la que se refiere es: " ?nombre crlf)
)

(deffacts frutas
    (fruta (nombre Melocoton) (color naranja) (semilla hueso) (tipo-piel aterciopelada) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Albaricoque) (color amarillo) (semilla hueso) (tipo-piel aterciopelada) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Ciruela) (color morado) (semilla hueso) (tipo-piel lisa) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Cereza) (color rojo) (semilla hueso) (tipo-piel lisa) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Aguacate) (color verde) (semilla hueso) (tipo-piel rugosa) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Mandarina) (color naranja verde) (semilla multiple) (tipo-piel rugosa) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Limon) (color verde amarillo) (semilla multiple) (tipo-piel rugosa lisa) (crece-en arbol))
    (fruta (nombre Melon) (color naranja amarillo) (semilla multiple) (tipo-piel rugosa lisa) (crece-en planta))
    (fruta (nombre Sandia) (color verde) (semilla multiple) (tipo-piel lisa) (crece-en planta))
)

(reset)

(run)
```

I havent found a way to create a rule for additional options the user may insert, and I would like to know if there's something like the underscore (_) used in visual prolog for these types of rule when working with a guessing program.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **not** conditional element in another rule to determine that there is no matching fruit:

```
(defrule no-buscar-fruta
    (color ?color)
    (semilla ?semilla)
    (tipo-piel ?tipo-piel)
    (crece ?crece-en)
    (not (fruta (nombre ?nombre) (color $? ?color $?) (semilla ?semilla) (tipo-piel $? ?tipo-piel $?) (crece-en ?crece-en)))
    =>
    (printout t "La fruta a la que te refieres no se encuentra." crlf)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gary! I'm now wondering how can i use sentences as input in the program, so the user can input something like 'azul oscuro'

Comment: Use (explode$ (readline)) to grab the input instead of (read). That will split the string input into multiple values.